# props variable doesn't update

Tags: reactjs

I've got a scene that spawns in a drawing component.
With this component I give some data: scene, mouseOffset and zoomFactor.

He gets everything succesful and when I update the mouseOffset in my scene it is also updated in the drawing component. But when I update zoomFactor it is not updated.

Here I give the props in scene:

```jsx
<Drawing scene={this.scene} mouseOffset={this.mouseOffset} zoomFactor={this.zoomFactor} />
```

And here I set them in drawing component.

```js
class Drawing extends Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        // Declaring variables
        this.scene = props.scene;
        this.mouseOffset = props.mouseOffset;
        this.zoomFactor = props.zoomFactor;
    }
 }
```

Now like I said when I update mouseOffset it updates the mouseOffset in drawing component but when I update zoomFactor it does not update, even though I do exactly the same with both.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `mouseOffset ` is getting updated or showing right value on initial componentMount.

Comment: Well I do understand that of course, but how come that the mouseOffset is updated? That is litterally the only place where I set it.

Comment: You need to use `this.props.zoomFactor`, because that's the one that changes.

Comment: @QuentinMussche Something else must be going on then regarding the mouse offset. Post a proper [mcve] and we can take a look.

Comment: You are convinced that `this.mouseOffset` is getting updated, but I still doubt that's the case. Just put the relevant code on https://codesandbox.io/ and we can take a look.

Comment: Well I triple checked, this.mouseOffset gets updated in drawing component when I change the value of it in scene component. But it does not do the same with this.zoomFactor

Comment: Or even better, build a minimal, complete, and verifiable example using the Stack Snippets so it's reproducible in the question itself.

Comment: Is `this.props.zoomFactor` being used in the component?

Answer (score 0):

So I got my update fixed.

I used: 
`this.setState({zoomFactor: this.zoomFactor});` in scene component.

And used: `componentWillReceiveProps()` in the drawing component.

Now my zoomFactor gets updated.
But so does mouseOffset still...

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  
  this.zoomFactor = nextProps.zoomFactor;

 }
```

So even though my problem is solved, how is this possible?

Comment: Can you *please* put your entire classes somewhere online and link us to them so we can find the error?